# Firebase realtime database add rule based on child

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have put a rule as

```
(root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('role/cafe').val() === true)
```

in my realtime database rules.

My user is

```
key {
 uid: xxxx 
 name: xxxx
 role:{
  cafe: true
  user: false
  }
}
```

if auth.uid is equal to key, the rule works, however how can I modify the above rule to look for uid inside data

Comment: What is the expected value of `$key`? How do you get the value of `$key` when you want to look up a user's data (such as in another rule)? For these reasons, I highly recommend against making it anything other than the user ID and using lookup indexes (e.g. username: uid).

Answer (score 4):

It is unclear what the value of `$key` is expected to be. So I'm going to assume it's just some random string that isn't used in the rules.

For each security rule, the current data of the node is accessible using the [predefined variable](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#predefined_variables) `data`. `".write"` and `".validate"` rules also have access to the to-be-written data as `newData`. These are both [RuleDataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#ruledatasnapshot_methods) objects.

Assuming that a user making changes must be the user given by the `uid` property, the following rules can be used.

```
"rules": {
  "users": {
    "$key": {
      ".read": "auth != null && data.child('uid').val() == auth.uid",
      ".write": "auth != null && ((data.exists() && data.child('uid').val() == auth.uid) || (!data.exists() && newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid)"
    }
  }
}
```

The above rules use a [fail-fast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) approach. If a user is not logged in, the check aborts. Otherwise, the user's ID is matched against the existing data at the given node. If the data doesn't yet exist, the newly updated data must also match the current user's ID.

In case the "cafe" role is important, the following rules also require that the "cafe" is set to `true` to allow read/write operations.

```
"rules": {
  "users": {
    "$key": {
      ".read": "auth != null && data.child('uid').val() == auth.uid && data.child('role/cafe').val() == true",
      ".write": "auth != null && ((data.exists() && data.child('uid').val() == auth.uid && data.child('role/cafe').val() == true) || (!data.exists() && newData.child('uid').val() == auth.uid && newData.child('role/cafe') == true))"
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** If `$key` is storing user info/data, I highly recommend using the user's ID as the key as security rules cannot perform queries like "does userid have admin role?" without structuring your data to allow it. If `$key` is meant to be a username, instead use a username-to-userID map as it will prevent future problems. One such example is if a user wants to change their username, you can remove and link the new username to the user without ever having to move all their data.

Comment: key is the auto generated id by firebase

Answer (score 2):

You can use a wild card. In your rules

```
"users":{
  "$key":{
    ".read" : (root.child('users'+$key).child('role/cafe').val() === true) && (root.child('users'+$key).child('uid').val() === auth.uid  ),
    ".write" : (root.child('users'+$key).child('role/cafe').val() === true  ) &&(root.child('users'+$key).child('uid').val() === auth.uid  )
  }
},
```

The first condition checks whether the café value for the user is true the second checks whether the uid is the same